# How install happybase

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, happybase

I cannot install happybase on Ubuntu linux 12.04, Python 2.7. I've tried `pip install happybase`. but I get an error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The error is:

```
error: invalid command 'egg_info'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
```

Comment: What platform are you on? If Mac, are you using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, or a third-party version? What version of `setuptools` do you have?

Comment: Also, I've seen errors like this from someone who somehow managed to install `distribute` 0.6 over top of `setuptools` 0.7+, which isn't supposed to be possible but I guess if you're determined enough… So, do you have any version of `distribute`, and, if so, what version?

Comment: Indeed, i think this has to do with broken setuptools/distribute/pip, not with happybase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade the setuptools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If not try this:

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

Comment: First, nothing about his question indicates that he's using a virtualenv at all; the fact that it's trying to install into `/usr/local/bin` pretty strongly implies that he's not. Second, you should never have to use `sudo` with a virtualenv.

Comment: I'm not using a virtualenv, I got it to work without one on another PC. I tried sudo, similar error. pip is up to date.

Comment: This is just assuming that there's something wrong with the permissions of his user profile.

Comment: Try the upgrade for setup tools.

Comment: sudo easy_install -U setuptools did it. Many thanks!!! I'll accept your answer when I can (in 2 minutes).